# Using a variable as an object and a function

Tags: javascript, function, object, mocking

I am trying to mock the `times` function from the JavaScript library [Underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/#times).

This function accepts two syntaxes :

```
_.times(3, function(n) {
    console.log("hello " + n);
});
```

and

```
_(3).times(function(n) {
    console.log("hello " + n);
});
```

So far I succeeded to mock the first one by creating an `_` object like this :

```
var _ = {
    times: function(reps, iteratee) {
        // a loop
    }
};
```

And the second syntax by creating an `_` function which returns an object :

```
function _(n) {
    return {
        times: function(iteratee) {
            // a loop
        }
    };
}
```

But I can't use these 2 methods together. I need to find a way that will allow both syntaxes.
Do you have any idea how I could use the `_` character as an object as well as a function ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Functions are objects in Javascript, so you could just do something like this:

```
var _ = function(a,b) { /* ... */ };
_.times = _;
```

Comment: There's more to it than just this to make `_(3).times(fn)` work.  You have to return an object from the function that both captures the `3` in instance data and the object has the `.times()` method on it.

Comment: @jfriend00 You are correct, but it doesn't have to actually do any work if OP is just trying to mock it, right?

Comment: The OP wants something that works.  I think their term "mock" here means they want to ***copy*** the way `.times()` works.

Comment: Thanks, this worked! (although I wrote a new function for `_.times = `. (And yes, by "mocking" I meant copy the way this function works ;-) )

Answer (score 5):

You should be able to combine two syntaxes like this:

```
var _ = (function() {

    var times = function(n, iteratee) {
        // a loop
    };

    function _(n) {
        return {times: function(iteratee) {
            return times(n, iteratee);
        }}; // or shorter: {times: times.bind(null, n)}
    }

    _.times = times;

    return _;
})();
```

Here you benefit from the fact that functions are also objects and hence can have properties.

Comment: This is perfect if you add something like if(arguments.length > 1){ times(n, arguments[1]); } before the return inside function _(n) ...

Answer (score 0):

You could extent the function after defining it. Try this:

```js
function _(n) {
  return {
    times: function(iteratee) {
      while (n-- > 0)
        iteratee();
    }
  };
}

_.times = function(reps, iteratee) {
  while (reps-- > 0)
    iteratee();
};

function iter() {
  console.log('iter!');
}

_(3).times(iter);

console.log('----');

_.times(5, iter);
```